# How to export canvas with background-image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can't export canvas with background. I have background change in canvas but i can`t export it. And how to make export button? How to do it?

```js
const btnExport = document.querySelector('#btnExport');
const imgConverted = document.querySelector('#imgConverted');
const myCanvas = document.querySelector('#mainCanvas_front');

btnExport.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      document.location.href = "share/share.html";
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(mainCanvas_front.msToBlob(), "Creatly.png");
    } else {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      document.location.href = "share/share.html";

      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.href = myCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
      a.download = "Creatly.png";
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
  }, 3800)
});
```

Comment: Create complete snippet please.

Comment: Did you set the background image using CSS?

Comment: @Max Yes, but i use style in html to make it flexible for make it changeable.